# pip install hyperopt and hyperas fail

Tags: python

I was trying to install hyperopt, but I got the following error:

```
Collecting hyperopt
Using cached hyperopt-0.0.2.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
DEBUG:root:distribute_setup.py not found, defaulting to system setuptools
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-gmhldfe7/hyperopt/setup.py", line 119, in <module>
    if package_data is None: package_data = find_package_data(packages)
  File "/tmp/pip-build-gmhldfe7/hyperopt/setup.py", line 102, in find_package_data
    for subdir in find_subdirectories(package):
  File "/tmp/pip-build-gmhldfe7/hyperopt/setup.py", line 73, in find_subdirectories
    subdirectories = os.walk(package_to_path(package)).next()[1]
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gmhldfe7/hyperopt/
```

And I got the same error when intalling hyperas. But I can install ggplot successfully by using `pip` command. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 3.5.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a bug in `hyperopt`. `generator.next` was renamed to `generator.__next__` which can be invoked with `next(generator)` in Python3.

Here is [the PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3114/) detailing the change.

Looks like it was fixed in master but never released. You can install from git (which means github as well) by doing the following:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt.git
```